# while loop continuously executing

Tags: matlab, while-loop

I need to obtain the smallest length of a vector using derivatives, I have done the math work and have my formulas however I am asked to find the smallest length using matlab in a directed search by something similar to the code below

```
    D_v=[dLdx dLdy];

    LD=norm(D_v)

    while LD > (10^-3)
        newx=Dx-0.01*dLdx;
        newy=Dy-0.01*dLdy;

        newdLdx = (newx-Ax)/sqrt((newx-Ax)^2+(newy-Ay)^2)+(newx-Bx)/sqrt((newx-Bx)^2+(newy-By)^2)+(newx-Cx)/sqrt((newx-Cx)^2+(newy-Cy)^2);
        newdLdy = (newy-Ay)/sqrt((newy-Ay)^2+(newx-Ax)^2)+(newy-By)/sqrt((newy-By)^2+(newx-Bx)^2)+(newy-Cy)/sqrt((newy-Cy)^2+(newx-Cx)^2);
        newD_v=[newdLdx newdLdy];
        LD=norm(newD_v)


    end
```

this while loop just continues to run, the LD does not change, Im sure its something simple Im missing but I cant seem to find my error.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Could you share your data please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a minimal, reproducible example I can't be sure that this is the only bug, but this is definitely one of your problems:

Inside the loop, you define

```
newx=Dx-0.01*dLdx;
newy=Dy-0.01*dLdy;
```

but the `dLdx` and `dLdy` are not updated inside the loop.

So modify the code as:

```
D_v = [dLdx dLdy];
LD = norm(D_v)

while LD > (10^-3)
    newx = Dx-0.01*dLdx;
    newy = Dy-0.01*dLdy;

    dLdx = ...
    dLdy = ...
    newD_v =[dLdx dLdy];
    LD = norm(newD_v)
end
```

Comment: you were right!  they were not updating within the loop, I changed the newx and newy to just Dx and Dy which allowed them to update the LD.  Thankyou for the hint!